# Calculate row percentage difference in a dataframe for certain values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date       Type   Count
<date>     <fct>  <int>
1 2018-11-01 B      2
2 2018-11-01 A      4
3 2018-11-02 A      1
4 2018-11-03 A      4
5 2018-11-04 A      3
6 2018-11-05 A      2
7 2018-11-06 C      1
8 2018-11-06 A      1
9 2018-11-07 A      1
```

For each date in the data frame, there are 3 possible types (A,B,C) which may or may not exist (i.e. Count can be 0).

I would like to calculate the daily percentage difference between A and C for each day:

i.e. (A-C)/(A+B+C) * 100%

For example, for 2018-11-01 (A=4, B=2, C=0), the percentage difference should be: (4-0)/6 * 100% = 66.7%

The resulting table should be:

```
Date          Count
<date>        <int>
1 2018-11-01    66.7%
2 2018-11-02   some %
3 2018-11-03   some %
4 2018-11-04   some %
5 2018-11-05   some %
6 2018-11-06   some %
7 2018-11-07   some %
```

Is there a way for me to calculate this (perhaps using dplyr package) without having to loop through each date using a for or foreach loop in R?

I have tried to do something like this, but it does not take into account the possibility of A, B and C having a count of 0 (i.e. missing from the dataframe):

```
abc %>% group_by(DATE) %>%
arrange(DATE) %>%
mutate(diff = n - lag(n, default = first(n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `complete` to fill the missing `Type` with 0 using `fill = 0` and then perform the calculation. This is assuming you have max of only one value per `Date` for "A", "B" and "C".

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  complete(Type, fill = list(Count = 0)) %>%
  summarise(Count = (Count[Type == "A"] - Count[Type == "C"])/sum(Count))


#       Date   Count
#  <fct>       <dbl>
#1 2018-11-01  0.667
#2 2018-11-02  1    
#3 2018-11-03  1    
#4 2018-11-04  1    
#5 2018-11-05  1    
#6 2018-11-06  0    
#7 2018-11-07  1
```

Answer (score 1):

For calculations like this, I prefer reshaping into a wide shape so I can directly access to columns I'm taking differences of, i.e. to have columns A, B, and C. It's a little more verbose, but it gives me a better handle on what's in my data.

Similar to @Ronak Shah's answer, I'd first use something like `complete` to fill in any missing combinations of date and type. I'm also summarizing counts by groups, just in case there are multiple observations of any date-type combinations.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_complete <- df %>%
  group_by(Date, Type) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(Count)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(Date, Type, fill = list(Count = 0))

df_complete
#> # A tibble: 21 x 3
#>    Date       Type  Count
#>    <date>     <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 2018-11-01 A         4
#>  2 2018-11-01 B         2
#>  3 2018-11-01 C         0
#>  4 2018-11-02 A         1
#>  5 2018-11-02 B         0
#>  6 2018-11-02 C         0
#>  7 2018-11-03 A         4
#>  8 2018-11-03 B         0
#>  9 2018-11-03 C         0
#> 10 2018-11-04 A         3
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

Then using `spread`, I'm getting columns for each type, then doing the calculation. If you want to format as percentage strings like in your example, you can pass the counts to `scales::percent`, which will format 0.75 as 75%, for example. You can then drop the columns besides date and count, or in a more complex situation you might want to do further reshaping.

```r
df_complete %>%
  spread(key = Type, value = Count) %>%
  mutate(Count = (A - C) / (A + B + C)) %>%
  mutate(Count = scales::percent(Count)) %>%
  select(Date, Count)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   Date       Count
#>   <date>     <chr>
#> 1 2018-11-01 67%  
#> 2 2018-11-02 100% 
#> 3 2018-11-03 100% 
#> 4 2018-11-04 100% 
#> 5 2018-11-05 100% 
#> 6 2018-11-06 0%   
#> 7 2018-11-07 100%
```

Slight variation is using `rowwise` to group by each row, which lets you call `sum` on the type columns.

```r
df_complete %>%
  spread(key = Type, value = Count) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Count = (A - C) / sum(A, B, C)) %>%
  mutate(Count = scales::percent(Count)) %>%
  select(Date, Count)
#> Source: local data frame [7 x 2]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   Date       Count
#>   <date>     <chr>
#> 1 2018-11-01 66.7%
#> 2 2018-11-02 100% 
#> 3 2018-11-03 100% 
#> 4 2018-11-04 100% 
#> 5 2018-11-05 100% 
#> 6 2018-11-06 0%   
#> 7 2018-11-07 100%
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>